# New options and loaded class options bug?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I found some odd behavior that I can't seem to get around. I'm writing a new version of a class file I did a while ago that is based on the memoir class. Now, the memoir class has two mutually exclusive options: oneside and twoside (twoside is the default). In my class, I want oneside to be the default. So the top of my class file is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{mythesis}[01/01/2011, v1.0, my own thesis class]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
%
\newboolean{@myopti}
\setboolean{@myopti}{false}
\newboolean{@myoptii}
\setboolean{@myoptii}{false}
%
\DeclareOption{myopti}{\setboolean{@myopti}{true}}
\DeclareOption{myoptii}{\setboolean{@myoptii}{true}}
%
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}
\LoadClass[12pt,final]{memoir}
\ExecuteOptions{myopti,oneside}

 % <remainder of class code>
```

Which fails to make oneside the default. If, I change it to:

```
\LoadClass[12pt,final,oneside]{memoir}
\ExecuteOptions{myopti}
```

then if, in the main file I do:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{mythesis}
```

it remains in oneside mode.  The only way I can get it to work is to put

```
\LoadClass[12pt,final]{memoir}
\ExecuteOptions{myopti}
```

in the class file and then specify oneside if I want that (twoside is the default, remember, since I'm loading memoir).

But I don't want to have the user need to specify oneside since I want:

```
\documentclass{mythesis}
```

to be oneside.

I don't think this is a memoir problem, it's either a LaTeX2e problem, or an I-just-don't-know-the-right-way-to-do-it problem.

Gracias

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to do this correctly you should create an if-switch or boolean which is modified by the `oneside` and `twoside` options of *your* package, which then pass the final option to `memoir`. Note that you should process or execute your options *before* loading another class or package.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{mythesis}[01/01/2011, v1.0, my own thesis class]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
%
\newboolean{@myopti}
\setboolean{@myopti}{false}
\newboolean{@myoptii}
\setboolean{@myoptii}{false}
\newboolean{@myopt@oneside}
\setboolean{@myopt@oneside}{true}
%
\DeclareOption{myopti}{\setboolean{@myopti}{true}}
\DeclareOption{myoptii}{\setboolean{@myoptii}{true}}

\DeclareOption{oneside}{\setboolean{@myopt@oneside}{true}}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\setboolean{@myopt@oneside}{false}}
%
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}
\ExecuteOptions{myopti}
\ProcessOptions*
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@myopt@oneside}}
    {\PassOptionsToClass{oneside}{memoir}}
    {\PassOptionsToClass{twoside}{memoir}}
\LoadClass[12pt,final]{memoir}
```

Comment: Martin, Thanks, that makes sense, but I doubt I could have figured it out without seeing it somewhere (which I haven't) or having someone tell me. I see that I was unclear about the relation between my options and those from a loaded class, and a few other things. It's interesting that I can have the same option name as a loaded class, but not conflict.

Comment: BTW, I have the \ExecuteOptions statement in the correct place in my real code. I was just moving it around in my code to see whether, if I processed my options after I loaded memoir I could execute 'oneside' and, since memoir was loaded, it would get passed. I forgot to put it back when I pasted the code here. But thanks for your vigilence :-) .

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but I just found something... I ran into an identical problem, just with font size. What I found out is that you can use the command `\PassOptionsToClass{<options-list>}{<package-name>}` to set your defaults. *I'm a beginner*, so I don't know if this is actually wrong or is doing something I wouldn't want it to, but so far so good. So *I guess* your class code would end up being like this (I added Martin Scharrer's corrections):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{mythesis}[01/01/2011, v1.0, my own thesis class]
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{calc}
\AtEndOfClass{\RequirePackage{microtype}}
%
\newboolean{@myopti}
\setboolean{@myopti}{false}
\newboolean{@myoptii}
\setboolean{@myoptii}{false}
%
\DeclareOption{myopti}{\setboolean{@myopti}{true}}
\DeclareOption{myoptii}{\setboolean{@myoptii}{true}}
%
\PassOptionsToClass{oneside}{memoir}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}
\ExecuteOptions{myopti}
\ProcessOptions*
\LoadClass[12pt,final]{memoir}

 % <remainder of class code>
```

And then you can either use `\documentclass{mythesis}` or `\documentclass[twoside]{mythesis}`. Well, at least the MWE (with more options) I got here is the following:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{memtest}[2018/07/10 v1.0 Testing Memoir class]

% default options
\PassOptionsToClass{
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    openright, % openleft, openright, openany
    oneside, % oneside, twoside
}{memoir}

\DeclareOption*{
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{memoir}
```