# Adding the figures to a `draft` pdf

Tags: floats, pdfpages, draft

Suppose you have a `draft` pdf, and the only difference with a desired `final` version of it is the lack of figures. And suppose too you have the original figures, but not the source code of the document.

What would be your best trick to achieve the document with its figures on place?

Comment: What do you mean `draft` document? and why do you have `draft` enabled?

Comment: Probably the answer from [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13426/changing-implementation-of-draft-option?rq=1) question might help. In short: add the option `final` to the `graphicx` package.

Comment: @daleif, I mean one generated with ´draft´ option on in `documentclass` or `graphix` package, so it only has frames and image paths in the place of images. Also it is not very clear in the question, so I edit it, that you have not the original source code.

Comment: @crixstox, thanks and sorry, because the question was not complete. You don't have the `.tex`.

Comment: Then you would ave to edit the PDF in some program. Without the `.tex` you cannot run this through LaTeX

Comment: I am not saying this is the best way, but you could do this if you wanted to. If you included pages from the PDF as background images, you could then include the figures in the appropriate positions in the document. However, I cannot really think of any reason to do this. A better solution would be to use `pdfpages` to include the PDF and then lay the graphics over the top. But I am not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example with two images `tiger.pdf` and `flowers.eps` from `TDS:doc/generic/pstricks/images/`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=10mm,vmargin={10mm,20mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{tiger}%
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{flowers}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: without images]

Then I have measured the positions of the image boxes (using `gv`, ...):

```
\newcommand*{\imglist}{%
  \img{1}{118bp}{306bp}{301bp}{498bp}{tiger}%
  \img{1}{118bp}{65bp}{301bp}{204bp}{flowers}%
}
```

The first argument of `\img` is the page number, then the coordinates of the lower left corner and of the upper right corner follows. The following example will use the coordinate system of PDF (`gv`) with horizontal values from the left and vertical values from the bottom.
The last argument contains the image file name.

Then first a white box is put in the image area to clear the frame and image file name of option `draft`. Then the image is placed. It is assumed that the image is not distorted.

Package `atbegshi` is used to put the images on the foreground of the output pages. Package `picture` extends the `picture` environment. Also lengths values can be used instead of factors for `\unitlength`. Package `pdfpages` includes the original PDF file without images. And package `color` is needed for the white box.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand*{\imglist}{%
  \img{1}{118bp}{306bp}{301bp}{498bp}{tiger}%
  \img{1}{118bp}{65bp}{301bp}{204bp}{flowers}%
}

\newcommand*{\img}[6]{%
  \ifnum#1=\value{page}%
    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground{%
      \put({\dimexpr(#2)\relax},{-\dimexpr\paperheight-(#3)\relax}){%
        \rlap{%
          \textcolor{white}{%
            \rule{\dimexpr(#4)-(#2)\relax}{\dimexpr(#5)-(#3)\relax}%
          }%
        }%  
        \includegraphics[%
          width=\dimexpr(#4)-(#2)\relax,
          height=\dimexpr(#5)-(#3)\relax,
        ]{#6}%
      }%
    }%  
  \fi
  \ignorespaces
}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \imglist
}

\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{t.pdf}% PDF file without images
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]