# How to set default font size in latex cls file?

Tags: fontsize, documentclass-writing

I am using  a custom LaTeX document class for my thesis which is derived from the `report` class. I'd like to set the default size of the font to `12pt`, and still have the option to change it (to `10pt`) via the `\documentclass` command. How can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at [Difference between \LoadClass and \LoadClassWithOptions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9908/difference-between-loadclass-and-loadclasswithoptions).

Comment: The link above does not mention default options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

12pt is the default. The demo class is baz.cls

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{baz.cls}
\def\@@ptsize{12pt}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\@@ptsize{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\def\@@ptsize{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\@@ptsize{12pt}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[letterpaper,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany,\@@ptsize]{report}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass
%[10pt]
%[11pt]
{baz} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your modified documentclass file does *not* involve a `\LoadClass` call to LaTeX's `report.cls` file, it likely contains the following instruction shortly before the `\ProcessOptions` statement:

```
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany}
```

Change `10pt` to `12pt` in this instruction, save the documentclass file under a *new* name, and load this newly-modified documentclass file from now on. The default font size will now be 12pt, but this can be overridden by specifying `10pt` -- or, for that matter, `11pt` -- as an option. Of course, specifying the `12pt` option will now simply duplicate the default behavior of this document class.

**Addendum**: *If* the modified class file you're working with executes a `\LoadClass` call to the `report.cls` LaTeX document class, you may want to try modifying `\LoadClass{report}` to `\LoadClassWithOptions[12pt]{report}`.

Comment: that is a command in the original class and one should do all modifications _not_  int the original class! See Stefans comment ...

Comment: @Herbert: Thanks for this. I would definitely never suggest modifying an original class file. However, the OP's question seemed to indicate that he/she is working with a modified (hacked?!) version of the `report` document class which -- in all likelihood -- does not perform either a `\LoadClass` or a `\LoadClassWithOptions` call to `report.cls`. However, just in case that this assumption is incorrect, I'll modify my answer to make clear that the OP should save his/her further-customized documentclass file name under a new name.

Comment: \ExecuteOptions does not seem to work! I have put it in my cls file with 12pt option, but it still takes the default value as 10pt. Of course, changing the option in the latex document works. BTW, the option declarations in my cls file appear after the \LoadClass command -- is that a problem?

Comment: @Mico: I am not modifying the report.cls file. I am using \LoadClass to load report.cls.

Comment: OK, I see that the modified class file you have doesn't conform to my initial assumptions. See my modified answer for an alternative method.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted the actual code you use -- I seem to be laboring under incorrect assumptions about the structure of your modified documentclass file. :-(

Comment: @Mico: As I mentioned before, \ExecuteOptions have no effect! Does it matter where I put the commaand -- before or after the \LoadClass command?

Comment: @Mico: \LoadClassWithOptions[12pt]{report} does not compile. \LoadClass[12pt]{report} works, but it does not accept the option from main file.  

Here is the structure of my code:  

`\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}`  
`\ProvidesClass{iiscthes}`  

`\LoadClassWithOptions{report}`  
...  
`\ExecuteOptions{12pt}`  
`\ProcessOptions\relax`

Comment: `\LoadClassWithOptions{report}` is the correct code! Everything is declared in the link from Stefan!

Comment: @user1145885: I'm afraid that without seeing the code you're actually working with, it appears that I'm merely traipsing about in the dark.

Comment: @Mico: How can I send you the code? I pasted the relevant parts above, the the entire file is quite large!

Comment: @Herbert: It does not solve my problem -- changing the default behavior of the report class and still accepting options from the main latex file.

Comment: @user1145885: create a minimal template of your file and post it into your question, then we'll see.

Comment: @Herbert: Please see my comment before your last comment.

Comment: [This link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12933/new-options-and-loaded-class-options-bug) seems to be the answer.

Comment: @user1145885: see my example