# How to process base document class options in the derived class?

Tags: document-classes, documentclass-writing, class-options

I want to process options passed to the base class in my derived class. Specifically, I'd like to enforce margin sizes for the `article` class with `geometry` package.

Moreover, I would like to forbid certain layout options e.g. `twosided`, limit paper sizes and specify defaults. The latter I was able to find [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455148/how-to-create-a-latex-class-with-default-parameters), but I was missing information about how to process the options in the derived class.

This is my MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myarticle.cls}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mymarticle}[2022/12/10 My white paper class]

\DeclareOption{a5paper}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{landscape}{\OptionNotUsed}
\DeclareOption{twosided}{\OptionNotUsed}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[oneside]{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{left=10bp, right=10bp, top=10bp}{geometry}
\@ifclasswith{article}{a4paper}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{bottom=20bp}{geometry}
}
{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{bottom=40bp}{geometry}
}
\RequirePackage{geometry}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{myarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

This does what I want, but I don't think is the best way of achieving what I want. In particular, `ifclasswith` would require substantial nesting if I wanted to support 3 options or combining with `twocolumns`.

Comment: You could just `\DeclareOption{a4paper}{<your code>\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}}`. For instance you could add your own conditional this way. `\newif\ifmyarticle@aIVpaper\DeclareOption{a4paper}{\myarticle@aIVpapertrue\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}}` and then instead of `\@ifclasswith` you could use `\ifmyarticle@aIVpaper`. But I guess avoiding some nesting of conditionals is impossible (slightly depends on how the rest of your behaviour should be defined).

Comment: Of course you could also just pass your options to `geometry` with something like `\DeclareOption{a4paper}{\PassOptionsToPackage{bottom=10bp,a4paper}{geometry}\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{article}}`. Also, if your class got the option `a4paper` that'll be in the global options list that `geometry` will pick up, you don't need to explicitly forward that to `geometry`.

Comment: Thanks @Skillmon. That helps. I like the idea of using `PassOptionsToPackage`, as I can avoid code duplication. I am going to change the MWE slightly and refine my question. What I am still worried about is that there is no explicitly defined defaults just the if/else alternative. I am not expressing myself very well, sorry.